# Issue with google.visualization.Query class in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Actually, I have two questions about Query function:
1) How to assign an array from my ActiveSpreadsheet like a data source into Query? Is it possible?
When I'm trying to do this, as described at:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Using_the_Query_Language

```
var uniqueAddrs = new google.visualization.Query("http://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq?key=14msARLVvH5I17UIncJrx1JDTTtAKKDXTrF436SEe4rI")
```

Debugger tells me that "google" object is undefined. The same response I have when trying to add at the end of URL a Query request, encoded of course(like "http...someurl..&tq=select%20A%2C%20sum(B)%20group%20by%20A")

2)How to "pursue" Query understand UTF-8(Cyrillic symbols)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have written my very own query() and unique() functions. It was not so difficult as I imagined. Maybe, it will be useful to somebody:
Unique functions(returns unique rows from the array):

```
function getUnique(array){
   var uniqVals = new Array;
    for(i in array){
     var duplicate = 0;
      for(n in uniqVals){
        if(array[i].join() === uniqVals[n].join()){
         duplicate ++;
        }
      }
      if(duplicate === 0){
        uniqVals.push(array[i])
      }
    }
   return uniqVals
  }
```

Improved Vlookup function. Can return a value from needed column, which matches with 3 criteria in 3 different columns. Easy to add more criteria:

```
function vlp3(array,resultColumn,
                criterion1,criteriaColumn1,
                criterion2,criteriaColumn2,
                criterion3,criteriaColumn3){
   var matchVals = new Array;
    for(i in array){
    // var match = 0;
      if(criterion1 === array[i][criteriaColumn1] &&
         criterion2 === array[i][criteriaColumn2] &&
         criterion3 === array[i][criteriaColumn3]){
         matchVals.push([array[i][resultColumn],""]); //error arise without second element("") in row when trying getUnique it. Has no .join()method for single elements
      }
    }
    return matchVals
  }
```